# Настройка FTP на Ubuntu 16.04: не выходит залогинться из под root

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Стоит Ubuntu 16.04. Хостинг OVH - VPS. По умолчанию FTP не предоставляют. Как поднять FTP самому на Ubuntu 16.04? Находил инструкции как это сделать, но не выходит залогинться из под root.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vsftpd`. А sudo-пароль выясните у техподдержки. Или ОС Вы накатывали самостоятельно?

Comment: @kff пароль sudo я знаю. из под него захожу. Именно это и делал. Я не могу подключится из вне.

Comment: Вы хотите подключиться к FTP под root?

Comment: может у хостера настроен фаервол?

Comment: как анонимный пользователь вы может ftp воспользоваться? Если вы установили vsftpd, то укажите запущен сервис или нет, блокированы используемые им порты или нет, покажите места из `/etc/vsftpd.conf`, которые вы меняли. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте эту информацию туда.

Comment: @jfs У меня получилось сделать доступ для юзера `ftp` но теперь другая штука. У меня нет прав для записи, удаления. Чтение есть. И фигня в том что я не могу задать права. Я установил `Tomcat` и мне нужно сделать доступ по ftp к нему но штука в том что сайт не работает если `chmod` не настроен на пользователя `tomcat`

Comment: решайте одну проблему за раз. Если не знаете как настроить vsftpd, чтобы можно было не только скачивать, но и загружать файлы на сервер, то спросите специально об этом (пока ответов нет на данный вопрос, можете его по месту отредактировать, включая заголовок, иначе следует новый вопрос задать). Если ваш вопрос связан с более общей задачей (файлы для tomcat на vps загружать), то обязательно упомяните это в самом вопросе--возможно ftp это не лучший метод развёртывания tomcat сайта на vps.

Comment: @jfs tomcat уже установлен. для удобности заливки проекта нужен ftp. настроить я не могу. не подскажете?

Comment: *"настроить я не могу"* не информативно. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и явно укажите что вы хотите получить, какие шаги уже выполнили, что ожидали получить и что вместо этого происходит шаг за шагом. Нажмите [edit]